# Can i use the same content in two websites? one is the main website and one is directory website

Tags: multisite, content

For example. My first website is `www.example.com` and second is directory website `www.example.com/IN` where IN is India.

The main question is can I use the same content on both the websites for SEO?

Comment: This will have a negative effect as Google will view it as duplicate content.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is not a WordPress related website. And this site requires questions specifically about it.

To answer your question, YES. you can use the same content as long as it is on the same domain.

Comment: No my website is in wordpress

Answer (score 0):

You can do it. But Google will view it as duplicate content and will have a negative effect. You should move away from black hat SEO.

Wherever you have the same content on multiple pages without the correct reference, for example, Rel="canonical"  or a 302/301 redirect search engines will view it as duplicate content.

Comment: This one is really confusing as others told me that you can use it.

Comment: @ParthKiñariwala I have updated mu answer.

Comment: Ok Thanks. Do you have any solution for that? Creating subdomain is the way?

Comment: Better tell us what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: My full question is: I have a WordPress website www.example.com and I have used my own written content in it for SEO. Now the twist is I have to target the visitors in Australia so I will create subdirectory www.example.com/au with the same content used in www.example.com so can i used the same content for SEO?

Comment: No this still is viewed as duplicate content. So No need to do it just for SEO.